# Center view in superview via autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, positioning

I am trying to center my subview with a button in its superview. (I want tha distance from top-to-screen and bottom-to-screen be the same and the distance from right-to-screen and left-to-screen be the same) So I want the center of the subview be the center of the superview. I am trying that with following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()        

    var menuView = UIView()
    var newPlayButton = UIButton()
    var newPlayImage = UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs")
    var newPlayImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs"))
    newPlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newPlayImageView.frame.width, newPlayImageView.frame.height)
    //newPlayButton.setImage(newPlayImage, forState: .Normal)

    menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    menuView.addSubview(newPlayButton)

    self.view.addSubview(menuView)
    menuView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
    attribute: .CenterX,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: menuView,
    attribute: .CenterX,
    multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    )
    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
    attribute: .CenterY,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: menuView,
    attribute: .CenterY,
    multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    )
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following:
[image]

Comment: Sure that's the only/exact code you are using? The menuView is missing width/height constraints so it shouldn't be showing at all, and if I add those the layout is fine...

Comment: don't set frame for newPlayButton, set height/width constraints

Comment: also you can check out PureLayout, it makes it really easy to add constraints programmatically, as native API is unnecessary verbose, thus complicated

Comment: Just added Width/Height-constraints - Now it works! Thx :)